# Use type class to calculate the sum of each string's length

Tags: scala

I am learning type class of scala, when I look at the implementation of List.sum,I came out a question,

I have a list of string, say, `val x = List("one","two,"three")`, I want to calculate the sum of each string's length, namely, `x.map(_.length).sum`, but I would try to implement it using type class. It looks that I can't use List.sum  by providing instance of Numeric[String],I would ask if it is possible to do it with type class pattern, no matter whether to define a new type class or using existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that just implementing Numeric for Strings won't work because the sum method is defined to return the type for which the Numeric is defined, which would be a String.

Perhaps something like this?

```
trait SummableAsInt[A] {
  def plus(n: Int, a: A): Int
}

def sumListAsInt[A, B >: A](xs: List[A])(implicit s: SummableAsInt[B]): Int = {
    xs.foldLeft(0)(s.plus)
}

implicit val StringSumAsInt: SummableAsInt[String] = new SummableAsInt[String] {
  def plus(n: Int, s: String): Int = s.length + n
}
```

And it can be used like:

```
sumListAsInt(List("abc", "def", "ghi"))
```

If you want the same `x.sum` syntax rather than `sum(x)`, you could do it with an implicit class instead:

```
implicit class ListOps[A](xs: List[A]) [
  def sumAsInt[B >: A](implicit s: SummableAsInt[B]): Int = {
    xs.foldLeft(0)(s.plus)
  }
}

List("abc", "def", "ghi").sumAsInt
```

Comment: Thanks @joe-k. the anwser you posted should work,thanks